# Emirates contact via email

Tags: poland, emirates

I'm trying to contact Emirates Poland via email. I need to send them some scanned document (this is my initiative, they did not requested me for sending anything, but in my current situation this seems required). However, all that I managed to find is a local office's phone number and press / media representative (Aviareps).

Is there anyone I can get email for directly contacting Emirates?

Comment: Why don't you call them up and ask for a mail address? That gives you the opportunity to ask if they actually want a scan of your document.

Comment: @DCTLib this should be the answer not a comment (even if short).

Comment: @chx - Thanks for the endorsement. I answerized my comment now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Emirates does not have a publicly visible e-mail address *and* no contact form on their web page, they want to be contacted by phone.

So you should consider *phoning them and asking them for a mail address*. This also gives *you* the opportunity to check with them if they actually want a scan of your document (at this time), and this gives *them* the opportunity to give you an address of their department that deals with the type of request that you are having.